# Button in Horizontal Listview responds to setonitemclick listener of the listview row

Tags: android, listview, horizontallist

I have implemented `Horizontal ListView`. I have made the rows of the listview clickable. I have a `Button` in each Horizontal Listview row. On clicking the Button I want to show the facebook login dialog. On clicking the row I move to the next activity. My current problem is that when I click the button then the new activity pops up. can anyone help me with this. hope I am clear with the issue. My codes  are as follows:

```
 listview = (HorizontalListView) findViewById(R.id.listview); 
 listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {

                    Intent detail_item = new Intent(
                            TabMenuItemsActivity.this, DetailItem.class);
                    startActivity(detail_item);
                    finish();
                }
            });



     @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.category_item, null);
        Button fbShare = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_fblogin);
      fbShare.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            //code for fb
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making ListView focusable using `android:focusable="true"` and your button as non-focusable using `android:focusable="false"`

Answer (score 0):

you need to call the method `setItemsCanFocus()` on your listview:

```
listview.setItemsCanFocus(true);
```

In this way, you indicate that views created by the ListAdapter can contain focusable items.

Comment: It does not help. Any other suggestions